# BigQuery in Dataflow fails to load data from Cloud Storage: JSON object specified for non-record field

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Dataflow pipeline running locally on my machine writing to BigQuery. BigQuery in this batch job, requires a temporary location. I have provided one in my Cloud Storage. The relevant parts are:

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    options.as(BigQueryOptions.class)
            .setTempLocation("gs://folder/temp");
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

....

List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
      fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("uuid").setType("STRING"));
      fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("start_time").setType("TIMESTAMP"));
      fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("end_time").setType("TIMESTAMP"));
      TableSchema schema = new TableSchema().setFields(fields);

session_windowed_items.apply(ParDo.of(new FormatAsTableRowFn()))
      .apply(BigQueryIO.Write
      .withSchema(schema)
      .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
      .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
      .to("myproject:db.table"));
```

Where for `FormatAsTableRowFn` I have:

```
static class FormatAsTableRowFn extends DoFn<KV<String, String>, TableRow>
implements RequiresWindowAccess{  
    @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
          TableRow row = new TableRow()
              .set("uuid", c.element().getKey())
              // include a field for the window timestamp
             .set("start_time", ((IntervalWindow) c.window()).start().toInstant()) //NOTE: I tried both with and without 
             .set("end_time", ((IntervalWindow) c.window()).end().toInstant());   // .toInstant receiving the same error
          c.output(row);
        }
      }
```

If I print out `row.toString()` I will get legit timestamps:

```
{uuid=00:00:00:00:00:00, start_time=2016-09-22T07:34:38.000Z, end_time=2016-09-22T07:39:38.000Z}
```

When I run this code JAVA says: `Failed to create the load job beam_job_XXX`

Manually inspecting the `temp` folder in GCS, the objects look like:

```
{"mac":"00:00:00:00:00:00","start_time":{"millis":1474529678000,"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":true,"id":"UTC"}},"zone":{"fixed":true,"id":"UTC"},"afterNow":false,"beforeNow":true,"equalNow":false},"end_time":{"millis":1474529978000,"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":true,"id":"UTC"}},"zone":{"fixed":true,"id":"UTC"},"afterNow":false,"beforeNow":true,"equalNow":false}}
```

Looking at the failed job report in BigQuery, the Error says:

`JSON object specified for non-record field: start_time (error code: invalid)`

This is very strange, because I am pretty sure I said this is a TIMESTAMP, and I am 100% sure my schema in BigQuery conforms with the `TableSchema` in the SDK. (NOTE: setting the `withCreateDisposition...CREATE_IF_NEEDED`yields the same result)

Could someone please tell me how I need to remedy this to get the data inside BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Instant` objects. Try using milliseconds/seconds.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types

> A positive number specifies the number of **seconds** since the epoch

So, something like this should work:

`.getMillis() / 1000`