# BigQuery loads manually but not through the Java SDK

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Dataflow pipeline, running locally. The objective is to read a JSON file using TEXTIO, make sessions and load it into BigQuery. Given the structure I have to create a temp directory in GCS and then load it into BigQuery using that. Previously I had a data schema error that prevented me to load the data, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41341270/bigquery-in-dataflow-fails-to-load-data-from-cloud-storage-json-object-specifie). That issue is resolved.

So now when I run the pipeline locally it ends with dumping a temporary JSON newline delimited file into GCS. The SDK then gives me the following:

```
Starting BigQuery load job beam_job_xxxx_00001-1: try 1/3
INFO [main] (BigQueryIO.java:2191) - BigQuery load job failed: beam_job_xxxx_00001-1
...
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create the load job beam_job_xxxx_00001, reached max retries: 3
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:187)
at pedesys.Dataflow.main(Dataflow.java:148)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create the load job beam_job_xxxx_00001, reached max retries: 3
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$Write$WriteTables.load(BigQueryIO.java:2198)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$Write$WriteTables.processElement(BigQueryIO.java:2146)
```

The errors are not very descriptive and the data is still not loaded in BigQuery. What is puzzling is that if I go to the BigQuery UI and load the same temporary file from GCS that was dumped by the SDK's Dataflow pipeline manually, in the same table, it works beautifully.

The relevant code parts are as follows:

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    options.as(BigQueryOptions.class)
            .setTempLocation("gs://test/temp");
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options)
...

...
session_windowed_items.apply(ParDo.of(new FormatAsTableRowFn()))
      .apply(BigQueryIO.Write
      .named("loadJob")
      .to("myproject:db.table")
      .withSchema(schema)
      .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
      .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
      );
```

Comment: The first thing to do is find out what the error actually is. Take the BigQuery load job id (job beam_job_<xxxx>_00001-1) and either get the details from the command line (`bq show -j job beam_job_<xxxx>_00001-1`), or the via the your browser by using _"try it"_ at the bottom of the page (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get). Then you'll know more details.

Comment: I filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1235 to improve the error reporting.

Comment: Thank you @jkff that would be very helpful, and would have prevented this all in the first place :)

Comment: @GrahamPolley Thank you very much for this information. I debugged it form, however two things learned. Since there is a "job history" section in the BigQuery UI, I thought that is an exhaustive list and since my SDK jobs were not listed there I did not look for another job getter, it will be nice to also have the job getter linked to to the UI job history.

Comment: @plumSemPy So what was the error, and did you fix it?

Comment: @jkff - pretty sure the error used to be logged/shown in previous version of the SDK, right?

Comment: @GrahamPolley Possible. Much older versions of the SDK used to use a native implementation of BigQueryIO provided by the Dataflow service backend; it was reimplemented as a custom source in order to be runnable by all Apache Beam runners, and the error reporting was apparently lost in translation.

Comment: @GrahamPolley The error was a trivial schema mismatch. The thing is when loading data from the UI and via GCS, there is one schema and in that schema, in the UI I set the mode to be REQUIRED. Apparently, in the SDK the default value is NULLABLE and I did not know of `.setMode()`. Once I did `.setMode("REQUIRED")` in the SDK it was fixed.

Comment: @jkff - makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @plumSemPy - Terrific news! OK, I'll add an answer now so that others know what to do if they hit the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDK is swallowing the error/exception and not reporting it to users. It's most likely a schema problem. To get the actual error that is happening you need to fetch the job details by either:

1. **CLI** - `bq show -j job beam_job_<xxxx>_00001-1`
2. **Browser/Web**: use "try it" at the bottom of the page [here](http://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get).

@jkff has raised an issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1235) to improve the error reporting.